# Powershell ISE Doesn't Render the Client Area in Windows 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Recently, the Powershell ISE on my Windows 7 laptop developed a problem in which only the title bar and frame would render to the screen.  The entire client area (including menus) doesn't appear.  Instead, whatever is behind the client area shows through.  If I move the ISE around on the screen I get a client area with a jumble of pieces of the desktop or other apps that I drag the ISE over, as well as some ISE frame pieces.

I can blindly click in the area where I think the menu should be, and can occasionally get something to appear (a Save As... dialog, or some such), but the menus themselves are never drawn.

This started sometime during a period in which I didn't use the ISE, so I've no idea how many updates may have been automatically downloaded or pushed to my machine by my IT folks, and since I've no idea when it started happening they can't tell me anything either.

Any ideas on why a Windows 7 app in general or the ISE in particular could have this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could be video card drivers.  Try disabling windows areo to see if it's 3D driver related:

```
net stop uxsms
```

Also try running ISE as administrator.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Stopping aero made no difference.  Running as administrator made no difference. - Stumped

Answer (score 0):

On my system it's an interaction with MaxiVista (www.maxivista.com) which allows me to use an old laptop as a second monitor.

When the second (Maxivista) monitor is enabled, the Powershell ISE does not draw properly.  So @BryanVine is right.  It's to do with video drivers.